# Is it possible to access the placeholder name in a template?

Tags: django-cms

In Django CMS 3.4 I have a page with two placeholders `content` and `aside`. I have a plugin that may be inserted into the content placeholder or to the aside. When inserted into `aside` placeholder, I need a different class to output in the template. Something like this:

```
<section class="card {% if placeholder.name == 'aside' %} card--single {% endif % } card--image">
```

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question: It is possible. One can access the placeholder name from within a plugin template like this:

```
{{ placeholder }}
```

So if you want your template to behave different in a certain placeholder slot you could do:

```
<div {% if placeholder == 'aside' %} 
        class="asidecontent" 
     {% else %}
        class="maincontent"
     {% endif %} >
```

Comment: you my dear sir made my day. And this is working. Great if you need the output of a placeholder in the same template in two different places.